MSVC + ClangTidy fails for Boost in boost/config/auto_link.hpp after Visual Studio 2022 update to v17.10.3
I have a build system which uses

Visual Studio 2022 / MSVC (version 19.40.33811)
Boost (version 1.85.0)
ClangTidy (version 17.0.3)
CMake (version 3.27.4)
ninja (vesion 1.11.0)

All was working well until Visual Studio was updated to version 17.10.3. approximately 2 weeks ago. Now whenever I build for Clang-Tidy I get the following error:
build\Windows\_deps\boost-src\libs\config\include\boost/config/auto_link.hpp:478:77:
   error: pragma comment requires parenthesized identifier and optional string [clang-diagnostic-error]

   478 | #  pragma comment(lib, BOOST_LIB_PREFIX BOOST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_LIB_NAME) 
    "-" BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT 
    BOOST_LIB_ARCH_AND_MODEL_OPT "-" BOOST_LIB_VERSION BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX)
  |                                                                             ^
note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET'
44749 warnings and 1 error generated.

Could this be down to Boost not recognising the new compiler version when being build with clang-tidy under MSVC

This is a regression in whatever clang version your clang-tidy uses and should be reported as such. See this bug for an earlier report.

@Botje I have added a comment on that bug report. The version of Clang-Tidy which has not changed has building the project correctly. Only MSVC has moved on
